# 4k Image seems blurred

Tags: css, image, png

I have a 4k image that has text, in CSS is set to 90vh and 90vw (high and width), but in the page looks blurred, and when I zoom instead of losing quality it gets upgraded, how do I make it always have the full quality of the image?

I have already tried to use image-resolution and image-rendering properties but didn't work

Comment: Please put code into your question - a runnable snippet including the image and relevant CSS and HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example As a start, if you are forcing the dimensions of the img to be relative to your viewport it is likely to be distorted as the aspect ratios of the image and the viewport could differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a 4k image, it will remain a 4k image.

This is almost positively a result your eyes playing a trick.

There could certainly be distortion, however, if the image is being manipulated by anything else in the code, like CSS or JS.